# Using Bing Speech example with Curl

Tags: curl, speech-to-text, bing-api

First off, I don't really know what I'm doing, so I apologize for the stupid question... just trying to follow the instructions here:
https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/GetStarted/GetStarted-cURL

using cURL on Windows and entering this:

curl -v -X POST "https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?scenarios=ulm&appid=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&locale=en-US&device.os=windows&version=3.0&format=json&instanceid=e8ef8f76-2318-45d4-ac04-b73362ac61ec&requestid=73346a62-51fb-4aad-882b-9e5cd4198f57" -H 'Authorization: Bearer JWT'-H 'Content-type: audio/wav; codec="audio/pcm"; samplerate=16000' --data-binary @bing2.wav

Here's the output... any clues as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated:

```
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /recognize?scenarios=ulm&appid=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-
42B1D98141A5&local
e=en-US&device.os=windows&version=3.0&format=json&instanceid=e8ef8f76-2318-    45d4-
ac04-b73362ac61ec&requestid=73346a62-51fb-4aad-882b-9e5cd4198f57 HTTP/1.1
> Host: speech.platform.bing.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.50.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 314438
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 3BA3FD7E454246D69D3B1E6C436F0261 Ref B:     
8CD198CC061DC0914
B02FDF95CFEDBD6 Ref C: Sun Jan  8 15:06:41 2017 PST
< Date: Sun, 08 Jan 2017 23:06:41 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host speech.platform.bing.com left intact
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: Bearer/
* Could not resolve host: Bearer
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you format the command line properly it should work.

You miss the space before `-H 'Content-type...`, so that quote before -H is not properly processed. You also need to substitute the token you received on previous step properly after `Bearer`, not just put `JWT`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, the JWT was just a placeholder. The correct token was inserted. There is a space before -H. MIght not have come through in the above post, but just checked and it's there on the command line.

Comment: Provide the exact text then and a screenshot, it seems your edits are not consistent.